# Printing without blank lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, line, space

I just write print(bl). (bl is something that I scraped).
And is returning these.

```
                                                    ANT1440809






                                                    ANT1441876






                                                    ANT1442526






                                                    COSU6304518110






                                                    COSU6305225900






                                                    COSU6305225920
```

COSU6308165500

COSU6308432610

```
                                                    COSU6308437200
```

COSU6308546590

```
                                                    DXB0581358






                                                    EGLV480100024576






                                                    EGLV480100027435






                                                    EGLV751100045218






                                                    EGLV751100045749






                                                    EGLV751100046320






                                                    EGLV751100048004






                                                    EGLV751100048438






                                                    EGLV751100048446






                                                    EGLV751100048454
```

EGLV751100049540

```
                                                    EGLV751100050963






                                                    EGLV751100051021
```

EGLV751100051501

As you can see it begins with blank lines then the code I extract and then again there are blank lines between the codes, and they don't print in a column. How can I make it print like this?

Code1

Code2

Code3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `print(bl.strip())`. It will remove the whitespace surrounding the string